# I have a SQL Server 2000 database. How do I remove duplicate rows from a table without a key field?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I also do not have the ability to create a temp table to move data to, most of the suggestions I have seen either require a unique ID or the ability to create a table to move unique rows to. I also cant add a key to the table.

My table structure (relevant columns) is:

```
Customer_code, carrier, rack, bin
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT id, gid, url, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
     (PARTITION BY gid, url ORDER BY id) 
   FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT id,gid,url FROM x WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: And the `WITH....` statement (a **common-table expression**) also **isn't supported** in SQL Server 2000 ....

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.